# Rails - Ajax request doesn't load when I add .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to do a simple website, a stock tracker if you will. One of the features is getting the results using ajax, as not to load the entire page, I can go as far as to get the html with the data I want into the response, but cannot load it into the page. And when I add the equivalent js.erb file, I get no response at all.

Here's the page: (my_portfolio.html.erb)

```
    <h1> My Portfolio</h1>

<h3>Search for stocks</h3>
  <div id="stock-lookup">
    <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: "stock-lookup-form" do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true,
                           class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" do %>
          <%= fa_icon "search" %> Look up a stock

        <% end %>
      </div>


    </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>
  <div id="results">
    <%= render 'users/result' %>
  </div>
```

here's the partial that gets rendered at the bottom: (_result.html.erb)

```
<% if @stock %>
  <div class="well results-block">
    <strong>Symbol: </strong><%= @stock.ticker %>
    <strong>Name: </strong><%=@stock.name %>
    <strong>Price: </strong><%= @stock.last_price %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

here's the method that runs when you submit the form (stocks_controller.rb):

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search

    if params[:stock].present?
      @stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
      if @stock
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render partial: 'users/result' }
        end
      else
        flash[:danger] = "You have entered an invalid symbol."
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end

    else
      flash[:danger] = "You have input an unexistant stock."
      redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end

  end
end
```

here's my problem: when I submit a valid input, I check the server response in the browser and there I see the response text:

```
  <div class="well results-block">
    <strong>Symbol: </strong>GOOG
    <strong>Name: </strong>Alphabet Inc.
    <strong>Price: </strong>1042.1
  </div>
```

So that means that i am getting the data back, however, trying to put it on the page is not working, because when i create the appropriate `_result.js.erb`, the request does not return anything at all and the page isn't populated with the data, the request only returns 200 when there is no js.erb file. here's the code: (_result.js.erb)

```
$('#results').html("<%= j (render 'users/result') %>")
```

I have no idea what the error could possibly be. Could anyone shed a light on this?

Edit: The approved answer works, yes, but I found that you can also pass a render to change page content, and that `$('#results').html("<%= j (render 'users/result') %>")` actually tries to render the page, while the actual intent is just to get the html, for that, simply use `$('#results').html("<%= j (render partial:'users/result.html.erb') %>")` instead. However, the `html.erb` part seems strictly necessary, unlike everywhere else in rails. It'd be great if someone could point out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like you are close and the issue is conflating server rendered versus client rendered.  Your javascript example 
of

`$('#results').html("<%= j (render 'users/result') %>")`

Will only be rendered 1 time on the server, so it will have no impact on the client when you get a response from an ajax call.

For this to work it needs to be part of the ajax or fetch call and should looks something like this.

```
html_results_string = "YOUR RAW HTML RESPONSE"
$('#results').html(html_results_string)
```

Side note, i recommend against the id here as well.  Use something like a data- selector based on the id of the thing you are requesting.

Comment: But how would I get this raw html then?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the full extent of the question.  You would use a whatever you have configured on the frontend to perform javascript xhr, just guessing from your question it would probably be `$.get`.  The `html_results_string would be the result of that ajax request.